# What are the LayeredGraphPlot PlotTheme choice?

Tags: plotting, visualization

DiagramGreen and DiagramBlue are the only examples shown in the help file. I have tried a number of guesses (DiagramYellow, etc.) but can't find one that works.  Are those the only choices?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
GraphComputation`$GraphThemes // Column
```

[image]

```
themestyles = "GraphStyle" /. GraphComputation`$GraphThemes
```

> {"BackgroundBlack", "BackgroundBlue", "BackgroundGold",
> "BackgroundGreen", "BasicBlack", "BasicBlue", "BasicGold",
> "BasicGreen", "DiagramBlack", "DiagramBlue", "DiagramGold",
> "DiagramGreen", "DynamicHighlight", "SimpleLink", "SmallNetwork",
> "ThickEdge", "Vintage", "VintageDiagram"}

```
LayeredGraphPlot[{"John" -> "plants", "lion" -> "John", 
       "tiger" -> "John", "tiger" -> "deer", "lion" -> "deer", 
       "deer" -> "plants", "mosquito" -> "lion", "frog" -> "mosquito", 
       "mosquito" -> "tiger", "John" -> "cow", "cow" -> "plants", 
       "mosquito" -> "deer", "mosquito" -> "John", 
       "snake" -> "frog", "vulture" -> "snake"}, Left, 
    PlotTheme -> #, PlotLabel -> #, ImageSize -> 200] & /@ themestyles // 
  Multicolumn[#, 3] &
```

[image]

```
graphSpecificThemes = "GraphSpecific" /. GraphComputation`$GraphThemes
```

> {"ClassicLabeled", "IndexLabeled", "LargeGraph", "PointAndLine", "SphereAndTube"}

Replace `themestyles` above with  `graphSpecificThemes` to get:

[image]

Replace `themestyles` with `` ("Base"/. GraphComputation`$GraphThemes) `` to get:

[image]

and with  `` ("Stylesheets"/. GraphComputation`$GraphThemes) `` to get

[image]

Full list of themes:

```
allThemes = Flatten @ Values @ GraphComputation`$GraphThemes
```

> {"Business", "Detailed", "Marketing", "Minimal", "Monochrome", 
> "Scientific", "Web", "Classic", "BackgroundColor", "BoldColor", 
> "CoolColor", "DarkColor", "GrayColor", "NeonColor", "PastelColor", 
> "RoyalColor", "VibrantColor", "WarmColor", "BoldLabels", 
> "ItalicLabels", "LargeLabels", "SmallLabels", "SansLabels", 
> "SerifLabels", "ClassicLabeled", "IndexLabeled", "LargeGraph", 
> "PointAndLine", "SphereAndTube", "BackgroundBlack", "BackgroundBlue", 
> "BackgroundGold", "BackgroundGreen", "BasicBlack", "BasicBlue", 
> "BasicGold", "BasicGreen", "DiagramBlack", "DiagramBlue", 
> "DiagramGold", "DiagramGreen", "DynamicHighlight", "SimpleLink", 
> "SmallNetwork", "ThickEdge", "Vintage", "VintageDiagram", "Default", 
> "Earth", "Garnet", "Opal", "Sapphire", "Steel", "Sunrise", 
> "Textbook", "Water"}

```
Manipulate[Quiet[LayeredGraphPlot[{"John" -> "plants", "lion" -> "John", 
      "tiger" -> "John", "tiger" -> "deer", "lion" -> "deer", 
      "deer" -> "plants", "mosquito" -> "lion", 
      "frog" -> "mosquito", "mosquito" -> "tiger", "John" -> "cow", 
      "cow" -> "plants", "mosquito" -> "deer", "mosquito" -> "John", 
       "snake" -> "frog", "vulture" -> "snake"}, Left, 
    PlotTheme -> theme, PlotLabel -> theme, ImageSize -> 500]], 
 {theme, allThemes}]
```

[image]

Comment: Homerun! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the contextual menu (as you enter the option `PlotTheme ->` ), in the documentation for [`PlotTheme`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html), and in the documentation for [`LayeredGraphPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LayeredGraphPlot.html)

```
Manipulate[
 LayeredGraphPlot[{"John" -> "plants", "lion" -> "John", "tiger" -> "John", 
   "tiger" -> "deer", "lion" -> "deer", "deer" -> "plants", 
   "mosquito" -> "lion", "frog" -> "mosquito", "mosquito" -> "tiger", 
   "John" -> "cow", "cow" -> "plants", "mosquito" -> "deer", 
   "mosquito" -> "John", "snake" -> "frog", "vulture" -> "snake"}, Left, 
  PlotTheme -> theme],
 {{theme, Automatic}, {Automatic, "Business", "Classic", "ClassicDiagram", 
   "Default", "Detailed", "DiagramBlue", "DiagramGreen", "Marketing", 
   "Minimal", "Monochrome", "Scientific", "Web"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I was changing the plot theme in the example and seeing if it worked.  I actually forgot about doing about it that way.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: `PlotTheme` is not an option for `LayeredGraphPlot`, which is the message I receive when I run yours and @kglr's code. I simply cannot replicate any of the codes given here. I use MMA 11.3 version.

Comment: @TugrulTemel - `LayeredGraphPlot` was updated in both v12.0 and v12.1

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: Does it mean that I cannot reproduce your code? `Manipulate` looks like a basic operation to generate graphs with different styles.

Comment: @TugrulTemel - you would need to define sets of options that produce the equivalent of the various `PlotThemes` and have the `Manipulate` control select amongst these sets.